# MongoDB projection referenced document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have `Order` document like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55fdd76fe4b08bcb851be855"), "customer" : DBRef("customer", ObjectId("55fdd76fe4b08bcb851be853")) }
```

And I would like to "printout" names of referenced customer like this:

```
db.order.find({}, {"customer.firstName":1})
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Dot notation works for `subdocuments` but not for `referenced` documents.

Is there is way how to "join" those tables or just tell mongo shell to fetch the customer document?

Comment: You need to fetch the document.

Answer (score 0):

The **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** method on the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** cursor can be useful in loading the customer references. Something like the following:

```
db.orders.findOne().forEach(function (order){
    var customer = db[order.$ref].findOne({"_id": order.$id});
    printjson(customer.firstName);
});
```